unity sprite and uı scaling
there are problems with the sprites I added to the screen (UI) in Unity. For example, there is a button and 2 sprites on the death screen. The button appears while the apk is running, but the sprite is not scaled and scrolls. I set the sprites in the scene and see them in the game, but they do not appear when the apk is printed. Likewise, when you make a simulator, the image shifts when you switch from one device to another. After I set the scene, I want it to be the same in the simulator as it looks in the game. How can I do it, thank you in advance.
I tried setting canvas but it didn't work. I'm new to Unity, but I'm sure there is no problem with my codes.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think you've an issue with the way you've define your UI scaling.
The best way is to set your canvas to scale with screen size and define a reference resolution according to the one in your editor/simulator. I also recommend to set the scale on match height only for a landscape game and width for portrait.
You can then set anchors to define where each element will try to place itself.
Find more information there : https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html
